# Не работает JS файл

Tags: javascript

Начнём с того, что это мой второй в жизни JS-файл для второй в жизни пробной верстки. Использую Brackets. Ничего не работает и пишет такие 3 ошибки:

1. ESLint: ERROR: parsing error: the keyword 'const' is reserved.
2. JSLint: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const'.
3. Stopping. (8% scanned).

При этом в браузере в консоли ничего не появляется, как бы усердно я не кликал на кнопку.

Вот код JS:

```
//classes
const headerBtn = document.querySelector ('.header__btn');
const darkBackground = document.querySelector('.dark__background');
//functions
function darkBackgroundShow() {
    darkBackground.classList.add ('dark__background__show');
}
//other
headerBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    darkBackground.classList.add ('dark__background__show');
}); //не работает

headerBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log ('click');
});//не работает

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    console.log (scrollPos);
});//не работает

headerBtn.addEventListener('click', function darkBackgroundShow());//не работает
```

Может я его не правильно подключил к html? Делал я это таким образом перед закрывающимся тегом body `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Я просто не понимаю, что от меня хотят, что мне сделать?

Comment: попробуй настроить `.eslintrc`  примерно так `{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },

    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}`

Comment: В коде вопроса только одна синтаксическая ошибка (в последней строке), тогда как вывод линтера явно говорит о том что ошибки допущены и где-то выше (в том коде, который в вопросе не приведен). Если же это весь код, то да, стоит проверить версию линтера (или настроить его, если он не настолько старый чтобы в принципе поддерживать ES6+... в случае если слишком старый, попытка настройки не будет иметь эффекта).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706706/6104996

Comment: @yar85 я тоже так подумал, но enSO  говорит, что такая магия бывает ↑

Comment: @yar85 Вы не могли бы мне, пожалуйста, подсказать, как обновить линтнер? Я буквально сегодня узнал что это такое, и как его обновлять и настраивать мне совершенное не известно

Comment: Если верно помню, линтер в Brackets является расширением, то есть обновляется/заменяется через встроенное в редактор управление расширениями (ищи в их списке ESLint). Но стоит учесть, что Brackets вообще крайне вяло обновляется (т.к. это изначально мертворожденный проект), поэтому более новой версии линтера для него может и не существовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начну с редактора кода: **1 марта 2021 года Adobe объявила о том, что с 1 сентября 2021 года прекращает поддержку Brackets. И предложила пользователям либо использовать исходные файлы с GitHub, либо установить Visual Studio Code.**

т.к. ты HTML не предоставил, можно только гадать что там, сделал свою реализацию.

Код: последняя функция `headerBtn.addEventListener('click', function darkBackgroundShow());`  все ломает, т.к. вызываешь функцию darkBackgroundShow() внутри слушателя события, а не в теле функции. Кинул на google диск **https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PdlpVeYsB3WWC7LYIYw-wjFj6HMTHn__?usp=sharing** там все работает, это довольно обширная тема, вот хорошая книга https://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html с 13 главы полистай. Не страшно что она на англ. просто переведи страницу в браузере если англ. не знаешь.